# How can i sell files using ubercart

Tags: 7, ubercart, files

I want to sell `files` as product using `ubercart`.

How to add files using product content type?

I want user to `pay for the file first` and then `get file downloaded`.

Is it possbile?Then how ??

Also i want each `role` called '`vendor`' to have there own `payment details` and `get paid from buyers`. Is that possbile?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is already module `File downloads` in the `ubercart` which allow user to sell `file` with the `product`.

- Install the module `File downloads` from the module list.

**Assigning directory to `file donwload`:**

- Go to `Administration -> Store -> Configuration -> Product`
- In the `File download settings` section, set the path of the `directory` of the files and save the form.

**Uploading files:**
- Go to `Administration -> Store -> Products -> View file downloads`
- Upload `files` into directory (which you have configured in above step) using `upload file` action.

**Adding files to product:**

- Edit your `product` and you will get the `feature` link in top of page. click on this link.
- In `feature` form, you can add `file download` feature to the product and it will redirect you to form to assign file to product.
- Select `file name` in `File download` text field. This is autocomplete field, so you need to configure correct files and save form.

When the user purchase product and pay the amount, it will send a link to user in his mail to download the files.

Regarding your second question, there is module [Ubercart Marketplace](https://drupal.org/project/ubercart_marketplace).

> Ubercart Marketplace adds multiple seller support to the Ubercart
>   module. It includes a series of modules that limit the access to
>   Ubercart functions for sellers. Additional functionality is added to
>   support this from both a marketplace seller's point of view and the
>   store administrator's view. Sellers (with the proper access
>   permissions) gain the ability to view their products, track and
>   fulfill their orders, and monitor their sales reports. Store
>   administrators can view seller reports based on seller order statuses
>   and seller sales. Support is included for Paypal Mass Payments, with
>   which an administrator can automatically pay his/her sellers for
>   custom periods.

Kindly see that Ubercart marketplace is still in development version for Drupal 7, so may be there could be some issue in this module.

Comment: In feature form, you can add file download feature to the product and it will redirect you to form to assign file to product. Select file name in File download text field. This is autocomplete field, so you need to configure correct files and save form. All this in drupal 6 or drupal 7 ? because in drupal7 i cant find those things.

Comment: This is for Druapl 7. Have you installed module `file downloads'?

Comment: yeah.. i got tat autocomplete field for file download. but its throwing me this error 
Error message
sites/default/files/new.png is not a valid file or directory inside file download directory. In the file downloads i have given this path(sites/default/files), File download settings also uploading files gave same directory.

Comment: @NewToDrupal, Your file download directory should be different to `sites/default/files` directory.

Comment: after adding the cart and after buying only i will get the pdf file or  wat ever file in mail ?

Comment: @NewToDrupal, Yes.. link in a mail to download file.

Comment: About second question, after adding to cart by buyer, then entering the details, i want that money to go to tat vendor only. Not to any other vendor. Like wise each vendor should get respective money for their files after clicking on add-to-cart and while paying after tat ?? is tat possible?

Comment: @NewToDrupal, Have you read my answer completely? I already mentioned a module for this.

Comment: yeah read tat, but this line makes me to ask that question , " Support is included for Paypal Mass Payments, with which an administrator can automatically pay his/her sellers for custom periods." BUt i want seller to directily paid after selling a product to his account, like wise for other sellers.

Comment: @NewToDrupal, I have not worked on this module, so you need to check module.

Answer (score -2):

There are so many tutorials available, i found it by Googling

> Many stores online deal in digital goods. Known Ubercart sites are
>   already selling music, photos, movies, and more using the core file
>   download system. Large sites like Riff Trax and corporations like AOL
>   are using this system to sell and distribute files. Props go to early
>   community member CpILL for getting the ball rolling and torgosPizza
>   for his extensive testing and use of the system. Its creation was and
>   its improvement continues to be a community effort.

https://www.google.co.in/search?q=ubercart+file+downloads+&oq=ubercart+file+downloads

[Selling Files](http://www.ubercart.org/docs/user/3345/selling_files)

[Setting Up Ubercart File Downloads](https://groups.drupal.org/node/56493)

Comment: Hello, The answer which is providing only link are not acceptable.